# How can I extract links from embedded links when web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am extracting data from a table of events from the website [here](https://runabc.co.uk/lancashire) and one of the columns I get is the title of an event, on the website it is a link to a different part of the website.
The link looks something like this 'https://runabc.co.uk/morecambe-marathon' where the event will depend on what event is clicked, however it is not exactly the same in the url as the name on the website so I can't always just add a paramater into a request.

Is there anyway to get the link when scraping the table? As well as getting the events name as I currently do.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Make the initial request
link = "https://runabc.co.uk/lancashire"
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

dfs = pd.read_html(link)[0]  # Select the first table from the list of DataFrames

# Specify the column names you want to keep
columns_to_keep = ["Date", "Event", "Location"]

# Set display options to show all columns and rows
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)

# Select and display only the specified columns
selected_columns_df = dfs[columns_to_keep]
print(selected_columns_df)
```

If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can get the data from the table into pandas DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://runabc.co.uk/lancashire"
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for row in soup.select("tr:has(td)"):
    date, event, location, *_ = row.select("td")
    all_data.append(
        {
            "Date": date.get_text(strip=True),
            "Event": event.get_text(strip=True),
            "Link": event.a["href"],
            "Location": location.get_text(strip=True),
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
          Date                                      Event                                              Link                                      Location
0  08 Oct 2023  Williams BMW Rochdale Half Marathon & 10K  /williams-bmw-rochdale-half-marathon-10k-fun-run                       The Esplanade, Rochdale
1  08 Oct 2023                   West Coast Half Marathon                     /the-west-coast-half-marathon                       Navigation Way, Preston
2  08 Oct 2023    Morecambe Marathon, Half Marathon & 10K                               /morecambe-marathon              Bare Methodist Church, Morecambe
3  12 Oct 2023                        Autumn Handicap 10K                                  /autumn-handicap  National Sports Centre, Douglas, Isle of Man
4  15 Oct 2023                         Autumn Breaker 10K                               /autumn-breaker-10k                 Stanley Park Arena, Blackpool
```

Comment: excellent mate!